# Inputting/importing MatButtonModule, MatMenuModule, MatIconModule into my project

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an Angular app, but I am not sure how I can add MatButtonModule, MatMenuModule, MatIconModule into my project.

Whenever I try to, I get the below error:

**"Module has no exported member"**

I believe this may have something to do with the Angular material installation but I am not too sure.

MatButtonModule, MatMenuModule, MatIconModule are all underlined as red in my IDE but I currently have MatFormFieldModule and MatInputModule and those are working fine.

Even if I add them to the Imports section, that does not help.

Here is my code for app.module.ts, does anything stick out:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';  
import { ItemService } from './items.service';
import { NewItemFormComponent } from './new-item-form/new-item-form.component';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule, MatButtonModule, MatMenuModule, MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/input'; 
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NavigationMenuComponent } from './navigation-menu/navigation-menu.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NewItemFormComponent,
    NavigationMenuComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule
  ],

  providers: [ItemService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: There should be no difference in implementing `MatButtonModule, MatMenuModule, MatIconModule`, It will be the same as `MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule`. Just import them in your app module.ts and make sure the import paths are correct. If not please create a Stackblitz to view complete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to import MatButtonModule, MatMenuModule and MatIconModule from input (@angular/material/input), which is not the correct way, you should import them from their respective modules like below

```
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
```